# MySQL process List

Tags: mysql, mysql5

We have a dedicated master server with 32GB of memory and 20 CPU linked to two other slaves , we are in constant need of restarting the mysql process due to memory issue .

When I run the  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST (Currently it's night so no one online)

I get this :

[image]

But when i go the server and launch the TOP command , i have **85** mysqld process :

[image]

Is that normal?

Here is our my.cnf file :

```
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve = 1


innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 128M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 64
table_open_cache        = 4000
#open_file_limit         = 10000
join_buffer_size        = 1024k
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed

# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2500
wait_timeout           = 150
interactive_timeout    = 30

# 80% of available memory
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 26G
#  The preferred value size for the log_file_size is 25% of the innodb_buffer_pool_size.
innodb_log_file_size           = 1G
#innodb_log_buffer_size         = 512M


innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 24
tmp_table_size                 = 256M
max_heap_table_size            = 256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
query_cache_limit              = 128M
query_cache_size               = 100M
query_cache_type               = 0
```

Comment: referring at https://askubuntu.com/questions/127257/is-multiple-mysqld-processes-for-1-mysql-server-is-normal, multiple mysqld shouldn't be an issue. You've set the buffer pool size to 26g and from your top command, it only utilized 23gb, your server still has 9g memory free. What exactly is the cause of you restarting the server?

Comment: 23G without any kind of usage (4:50AM) ... At peak it tops the memory and site becomes slow .

Comment: mm that's actually how MySQL works, the memory wouldn't be released just because there's no usage, they will just hold the memory for some sort of data/index caches so your next query can be fast without having to go through all the files with IO calls. You can set the limit using innodb_buffer_pool_size variable, mysqld may use at most a couple GB more than that, change innodb_log_file_size to 13gb for better performance.

Comment: although it says 80% of your total memory, I'd suggest you to leave it as 50%, so you can set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to around 16GB. See how much it goes at peak. Then slowly adjust it higher to somewhere you feel safe, always set the `innodb_log_file_size` to half the size of pool too.

Comment: if i set it to 13GB i get the following error : Error: combined size of log files must be < 4 GB

Comment: hmm weird, just wondering, when you say 13gb, what you put inside the ini file is actually '13G' right?

Comment: @ChorWaiChun Yes 13G , It was 1G

Comment: i think it's related to that : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33061/mysql-5-5-innodb-innodb-log-file-size-higher-than-4gb-combined

Comment: I see, my bad, in that case you may just leave it as 2G per file

Comment: Not even , anything other than 1 wont work , even 2G

Comment: hmm, try setting it to 2047M, as described on your link..

Comment: ok found the error it's related to log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size , i need to delete them before restarting

Comment: Great =) How's the server going? Does it still get slower after overnight?

Comment: I wasnt able to test since it's a production system ... dont want to mess with thing until i try on the staging side .

Comment: Turn on your general_log for 15 seconds.   Get a TOP while the general log is on to allow matching the pid # to the query running for research.  Turn OFF your general_log after 15 seconds.  Sounds like a CLOSE is missing (releases resources), unless you really have 85 concurrent connections doing something useful.